# An example of separation logic?

Tags: logic

Could anyone explain this example of separation logic?

What is the difference between the first line and the second line?

[image: Example]

Comment: This question belongs to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank for your comments, I will ask question in cstheory.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line says that the heap contains only one heaplet such that a reference x in the store points to it, and it contains the value `4,4`.

It is false in A because it forgets the heaplet pointed to by y (it does not characterize the entire heap correctly).

---

The second line says that the heap can be separated in two **disjoint** heaplets, such that one of them is pointed to by reference x and contains `4,4` and the second one can be anything.

In A, the second heaplet can be the one pointed to by y. In B, the second heaplet can be `emp`.

---

The third line is only true in A because in B the heaplets that point to `4,4` are not disjoint.

---

The fourth line is only true in B because it says that the entire heap can be described as containing `4,4` being referenced by x, and containing `4,4` being referenced by y.
It it not correct in A because A contains two disjoint copies of `4,4`, so it should be described using the separating conjunction.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the point. Could you see the second example below for me?

Answer (score 0):

These are axioms for separation logic. I can understand the first, second and the last, but I cannot understand the third one.

Could anyone explain it to me? What does `[X/x]` mean?

"every `x` in `e` will be replaced by `X`", is it right?

[image]

Comment: `{X = x /\ e -> Y} x := [e] {e[X/x] -> Y /\ Y = x}` says: Consider a heap with one location `e` containing some value `Y`, and the store location `x` contains a value `X`, then running `x := [e]` results in a heap with one location `e[X/x]` containing the same value `Y` and now the store location `x` contains value the `Y`.

Executing this statement does not affect the heap (there is still only one location containing value `Y`), but it affects store location `x`.

`Y` and `X` are just placeholder variables to relate before and after.

It is so general to cater for `x := [x + 1]` for instance.